# How to get or copy a background image in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel document, and I need to extract the background image from a sheet in order to put it in other sheets of this document. How can I do that? I would also like to extract it in order to modify this background with Photoshop. Is it technically possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Excel? If 2007 or newer:

- make sure the file is NOT in the old .xls format, but the new .xlsx format
- close the file
- copy the file in Windows Explorer
- rename the copy to have the extension *.zip
- extract the zip file
- find the image in the sub-folder xl\media

There may be several files in that folder if the Excel workbook has other images.

Now you have the image file and can insert it as a background to other sheets and/or manipulate it with Photoshop.

Comment: "If 2007 or newer" *and saved as .xlsx and not the legacy .xls format*.

Comment: good point. Added one step above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run winrar application
2. Select your file
3. Choose View file on ribbon
4. Find image in xl/media subfolder
5. Check jpeg file first

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the file is NOT in the old .xls format, but the new .xlsx format
2. close the file
   copy the file in Windows Explorer
3. rename the copy to have the extension *.zip
4. extract the zip file
5. find the image in the sub-folder xl\media

There may be several files in that folder if the Excel workbook has other images.

Now you have the image file and can insert it as a background to other sheets and/or manipulate it with Photoshop.