# Copying the background image in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use Excel 2003. I  have an Excel document, and I need to extract the background image from a sheet in order to put it in other sheets of this document. How can I do that?

Comment: [relevant](http://superuser.com/questions/598172/how-to-get-or-copy-a-background-image-in-excel) - I don't think it's possible with 2003 and xls.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just copy the Background from one sheet to another.  You have two options:

1. Copy the entire worksheet and the Background will copy with it
2. Extract the picture to an external **.jpg** file and re-insert that file into whatever sheets you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack installed, "save as" the document as a `.xlsx` file, then change the extension to `.zip` and extract the archive. One of files in `xl\media` folder will contain the background image.